# Cannot resolve the collation conflict - Issue in SQL script

Tags: sql-server

I am facing an issue in SSMS 2017. I am trying to setup a in-house application which runs the SQL scripts in backgroud. During the setup, I am getting below error:

> Exception: Failed to execute script:xxx.sql.. Cannot resolve the
>   collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and
>   "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the UNION operation..

I have tried following things to resolve the issue but it still persists:

1. Created the blank database with "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" as default collation and then ran the setup again.
2. Created the blank database with "Latin1_General_CI_AS" as default collation and then ran the setup again.
3. Tried changing the local language on server to English (United Kingdom) instead of English (Unites States) and then ran the setup again.

Point also worth a note is that other databases (which are working as expected) on the same SQL instance has default collation set to "Latin1_General_CI_AS". Also, I cannot make changes in the SQL script as it runs in the backgroud. I can only make changes in the SSMS Databases.

What could be causing this issue? Also, what else can I try to get this issue resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the database collation won't update columns that have already been assigned a different collation, so the question is: What are the odds that some of the columns in some of your tables might have mistakenly been set to a different collation during the creation of the blank databases that you tested? If you run the following query in one of those blank databases, do you get results?

```
DECLARE @COLLATION AS VARCHAR(128);

SELECT @COLLATION = collation_name 
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE database_id = DB_ID()
;

SELECT C.*
FROM sys.Columns C
INNER JOIN sys.Tables T
    ON C.object_id = T.object_id
    AND T.is_ms_shipped = 0
WHERE C.collation_name <> @COLLATION
;
```

If you have columns that don't match, you could try first executing a script that updates the collation on those specific fields, thereby allowing your second script to execute without error. If the script is dependent on matching collations, it might be a good idea to incorporate this check/fix anyway, since you might run into the same problem in the future.

Were the blank databases created from a script based on the old, problematic database? If so, I have to assume that something meddled in your collations in that database, and the problem is simply trickling down into your new, blank databases.

Answer (score 0):

> other databases (which are working as expected) on the same SQL
>   instance has default collation set to "Latin1_General_CI_AS"

This makes me think that your `Server Collation` is `Latin1_General_CI_AS`, anyway, you can check it this way:

```
select SERVERPROPERTY('Collation')
```

So your `server collation` is `Latin1_General_CI_AS`, but your application is using old (legacy) collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

I imagine it just has its tables with the columns having this collation, and now it runs its queries against your `system databases`, and all your system tables have `Latin1_General_CI_AS`, or it just creates temp tables that also inherit `Latin1_General_CI_AS` of your `tempdb`.

If you cannot access its code (it seems that application wrote you what files it was using: `xxx.sql`), you should instal another instance of SQL Server and during installation choose `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` as `server collation`.

If you can access the code that application executes, please update your question with it, maybe it can be changed using `COLLATE` clause.